# Return all rows with no activity in the past 12 months but have an activity in the current month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

| SALESPERSON | CUSTOMER | LOAD_ID | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | CUST1 | 001 | 5/10/2021 |
| ABC | CUST2 | 002 | 8/18/2020 |
| DFG | CUST3 | 003 | 6/12/2018 |

I want my query to return all customers who have no loads within the previous 12 months but have loads in the current month of May. So basically the query should return Loads 001 and 003.

Comment: Define *previous 12 months* - is that the same date in the previous year, the 1st of the current month in the previous year, or something else?

Comment: @Stu last 12 months from 2021-05-01. the previous 12 month period will be from 2020-04-01 to 2021-04-30

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()`.  I'm not sure if "previous 12 months" is 12 months before the date or the previous 12 calendar months, but the logic is like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
            lag(date) over (partition by customer order by date) as prev_date
      from t
     ) t
where date >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) and
      date < dateadd(day, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)) and
      (prev_date is null or
       prev_date < dateadd(month, -12, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
     )
```

Comment: .. a conditional max(null when date > May) over(customer) as prev_date would also cover the customers with more than one orders in May

Comment: @lptr . . . It wouldn't satisfy the condition that the previous order is more than 12 months in the past.

Comment: @lptr . . .That is a question of interpretation.  I think the OP wants one row per *customer*:  "I want my query to return all customers who have no loads within the previous 12 months."  I admit that the question is a little ambiguous though.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of obtaining the result. I used one approach and this is quite simple. Our logic is to get the rows which are greater than the previous period end  and less  than previous period start. Basically data does not fall in between the previous 12 months, if I am not wrong.

```
DECLARE @table_sales AS TABLE
(
 SALESPERSON VARCHAR(100)
, CUSTOMER VARCHAR(100)
, LOAD_ID INT
,[DATE] DATE )

INSERT INTO  @table_sales VALUES ('ABC', 'CUST1',001,'2021-05-10')
    ,('ABC', 'CUST2',002,'2020-08-18')
    ,('DFG', 'CUST3',003, '2018-06-12')

--Define the date periods. I used getdate and prepared the data from and date to
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE() , -1))
DECLARE @PreviousFrom AS DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @StartDate) )
DECLARE @PreviousTo AS DATE = DATEADD(DAY,-1, @StartDate)

SELECT *  FROM
@table_sales
WHERE [DATE] > @PreviousTo 
UNION ALL
SELECT *  FROM
@table_sales
WHERE [DATE] < @PreviousFrom
```

[image: Output]